# Cannot read property &#39;body&#39; of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm trying to put passport logic in controllers file but the problem is when i put the logic inside the controllers it's tell me "Cannot read property 'body' of undefined" but when i move the code to the index routes everything goes right

index.js/controller the problem is in " postLogin "

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const passport = require('passport');


module.exports = {
  async postRegister(req, res, next) {

      const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        image: req.body.image

      })

      await User.register( newUser , req.body.password);
      res.redirect('/');
    },
  postLogin(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/' ,failureRedirect: '/login' })();
  }
}
```

index.js/routes

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { postRegister, postLogin } = require('../controllers/index');
const { errorHandler } = require('../middleware/index');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Surf Shop - Home' });
});

/* User routs */

//Get register
router.get('/register', (req, res, next) => {res.send('/register')});

//POST register
router.post('/register', errorHandler(postRegister));

//Get login
router.get('/login', (req, res, next) => { res.send('GET /Login') });

//POST login
router.post('/login', postLogin);

module.exports = router;
```

image form postman

[image]

Comment: How does your `errorHandler` look like? have you tried passing `postRegister` instead of `errorHandler(postRegister)` in `router.post('/register', ...)`?

Comment: my problem with postLogin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the brackets intentional at the end of:

`passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/' ,failureRedirect: '/login' })() <----`

Issue with parameters not being passed?

`router.post('/login', postLogin);`

Becomes:

```
router.post('/login', () => { 
    postLogin(req, res, next) 
});
```

Correct resolve:

Very helpful but the parameters not being passed here

```
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/' ,failureRedirect: '/login' })(here)
```

So becomes

```
`passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/' ,failureRedirect: '/login' })(req, res, next)`
```

Comment: yes if i removed the brackets, the function will loading forever

Comment: Edited answer above to preserve formatting. Possible parameter issue?

Comment: very help full 

but the parameters not being passed here 

passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/' ,failureRedirect: '/login' })(here) <----


soo becomes 
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/' ,failureRedirect: '/login' })(req, res, next) <----

thank you ;)